# JavaScript - failing to use createJavaScriptNode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, html5-audio, webrtc

How to fix this?

[image]

its failing in past it was working fine but not anymore. 
(Normally it show green bar in the canvas if you speak in the mic.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var navigator  = window.navigator;
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia);
navigator.getMedia({ video: false, audio: true}, function(stream) {
  console.log('doing....');

    audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
    analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    javascriptNode = audioContext.createJavaScriptNode(2048, 1, 1);

    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
    analyser.fftSize = 1024;

    microphone.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
    javascriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    canvasContext = document.getElementById("test");
    canvasContext= canvasContext.getContext("2d");

    javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
      console.log('doing.... bla bla');
        var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
        var values = 0;

        var length = array.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values += array[i];
        }

        var average = values / length;
        canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 130);
        canvasContext.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
        canvasContext.fillRect(0,130-average,300,130);
    }

    console.log('doing.... done');
}, function(err) {
  console.log("An error occured! " + err);
});                 

</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`webkitAudioContext()` does not have `createJavaScriptNode` and I believe you should not use it anywhere.

Try `javascriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

`createJavaScriptNode()` has been marked as obsolete (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createJavaScriptNode), and it's use is now discouraged. Looks like the method name has been changed to `createScriptProcessor()`, here's some doc on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createScriptProcessor

Hope this helps!

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Yeah, a little googling turned up that the method in question is obsolete and likely removed in new versions of Chrome.