# getUserMedia give a error on Firefox, and silently fails on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio

Full Js code

```
        navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.msGetUserMedia);

        var session = {
          audio: true,
          video: false
        };
        var recordRTC = null;
        navigator.getUserMedia(session, initializeRecorder, onError);

        function initializeRecorder(stream) {
            console.log ("init Recorder");
            var audioContext = window.AudioContext;
            var context = new audioContext();
            var audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            var bufferSize = 2048;
            // create a javascript node
            var recorder = context.createJavaScriptNode(bufferSize, 1, 1);
            // specify the processing function
            recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;
            // connect stream to our recorder
            audioInput.connect(recorder);
            // connect our recorder to the previous destination
            recorder.connect(context.destination);
        }

        function recorderProcess(e) {
            var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            // window.Stream.write(convertFloat32ToInt16(left));
        }

        function onError(errorText)
        {
            console.log (errorText);
        }
```

When loading this page, Firefox executes the onError callback for getUserMedia. The error tells:

> NotFoundError: The object can not be found here.

Chrome, instead, simply does nothing.

Both FF and Chrome doesn't ask me for permission to use microphone. Why?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/cgc2y8br/. Maybe you're trying to do this on a `file:` page? If so, this may be a duplicate of [Chrome getUserMedia Not Requesting Permission Locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723699/chrome-getusermedia-not-requesting-permission-locally). (Also, you should use [`createScriptProcessor` instead of `createJavaScriptNode`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753557/javascript-failing-to-use-createjavascriptnode).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the page from a http(s) protocol. If you run it from file:// security restrictions kicks in.

Also, in Chrome `AudioContext` is prefixed so you need to change this line:

```
var audioContext = window.AudioContext;
```

to

```
var audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
```

In addition, [`createJavaScriptNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createScriptProcessor) is obsolete. Consider using [`createScriptProcessor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createScriptProcessor) instead.

(Eventually the `ScriptProcessorNode` will also be replaced, by **[Audio Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#Audio_Workers)** - not yet implemented in any browsers though, but something to be aware of for later).

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your microphone in Device Manager. Make sure have any available mic in system.